# AWS Lambda Jtest: How to ignore arguments on Handler class

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda, which works as expected, but when I tried to test it using Jest v.29 my test file is giving me an error:

An argument for 'context' was not provided.

This is my Lambda: **index.ts**

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';


export const handler: Handler = async (event) => {
  const method = event.httpMethod;
  if (method !== 'PUT') {
    return { statusCode: 401, body: JSON.stringify('Method Not Allowed') };
  }
  
  
  return {
    statusCode: 404,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello' }),
  };
}
```

This is my test file: **index.test.ts**

```
import { handler } from './index';

describe('handler', () => {

  it('should return the message "Method Not Allowed" if method is not PUT', async () => {
    const event = {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
    };

    const result = await handler(event);

    expect(result.statusCode).toBe(401);
    expect(result.body).toBe(JSON.stringify('Method Not Allowed'));
  });

});
```

I tried with:

- Adding null values to arguments like: await handler(event, null, null)
- Also with: await handler(event, undefined, null)
- And type Handler = (event: any) => Promise; on my lambda

None of those work, Any ideas how can I fix this error? because I'm not using Context or Callback from AWS Handler.

Comment: For fun, if you comment out the line `const result = await handler(event);` do you still get an error?

Comment: @possum no errors then.

Comment: Not what I was hoping to hear.  I'd probably shove it in a debugger and go step by step to see where it's actually trying to use context at this point.  I'm as confused as you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed. I added a mock of context and callback, only in the test file.

**index.test.ts**

```
    const context: Context = {
      awsRequestId: '',
      callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: true,
      functionName: '',
      functionVersion: '',
      invokedFunctionArn: '',
      logGroupName: '',
      logStreamName: '',
      memoryLimitInMB: '',
      getRemainingTimeInMillis: () => 0,
      done: () => {},
      fail: () => {},
      succeed: () => {},
    };

    const callback: APIGatewayProxyCallback = (error, result) => {};

    const result = await handler(event, context, callback);
```

You should do the imports as well:

```
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyCallback } from 'aws-lambda';
```